# Showing that X <= 16 inequalities question

Tags: inequality

I have the question " A rectangular birthday card is Xcm wide and (X+8)cm tall. Given that the height of the card is to be at least 50% more than its width,  show that X<=16."

When I checked the solutions to this question it states that

(X + 8) >= 1.5 * X,   However I do not understand where the 1.5 came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $1.5$ comes from the requirement that the height is $50\%$ more than the width.  That means the height must be at least $1+0.5$ times the width.

Comment: But why is it 1 + 0.5 and not just 0.5 * X ?

Comment: It is multiplied by $X$.  That is "times the width".

Comment: The second part to this question states that " Find the set of possible values of X given also that the area of the front of the card is to be at least 180cm^2"

Comment: However, it says that X > 0 as the width is > 0 and X <= 16 therefore,   10 <= X <= 16 I do not understand where this range came from.

Comment: If $X=0$ you don't have a card.  I suspect it says $X \ge 10$ and you just have a typo in the last comment.  Do you see why you know that $X \le 16?$.  Then to get the area you multiply the width times the height.  That is where $X \ge 10$ comes from-you need $X(X+8) \ge 180$